# Read requests per 100 seconds per user - not affecting Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to limit number of function invocations per user for Firebase Cloud Functions in the Google Cloud Platform. I am not sure if I understand what the `Read requests per 100 seconds per user` setting is as I have changed it down to 1 from 500 and a user can still make as many calls as he/she wants. From the information I found this should affect the end user.

Why are these setting not working for me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration for limiting usage of a function per end user.  The configuration you've shown in the question is not related at all.  It has more to do with the underlying Cloud APIs that operate Cloud Functions, for administrative purposes.

If you want to limit a function per UID, you'll have to build that accounting mechanism yourself.